# how can i release memory caused by "for"

Tags: python, memory, for-loop

Our game program will initialize the data of all players into the memory. My purpose is to reduce the memory which is not necessary. I traced the program and found that "for" taking a lot of memory.

For example:

```
 Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    52                             @profile
    53    11.691 MB     0.000 MB   def test():
    54    19.336 MB     7.645 MB       a = ["1"] * (10 ** 6)
    55    19.359 MB     0.023 MB       print recipe.total_size(a, verbose=False)
    56    82.016 MB    62.656 MB       for i in a:
    57                                     pass
```

print recipe.total_size(a, verbose=False)：8000098 bytes

The question is How can i release that 62.656 MB memory.

P.S.

Sorry, i know my English is not very well．I will appreciate everyone to read this.:-)

Comment: I fear your analysis is not correct here. All `for` does is create an iterator object for `a`, which is nothing more than a reference to `a` and a index value to track where in the list the iterator is at. **There really is nothing more**.

Comment: Which tool i used is memory_profiler.Although I do not quite understand it, it is welcome in github.(https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler)    If "for" didn't do anymore, where the figure (62.656 MB) came from?

Comment: My guess is that the `a` list is to blame here; on my 64-bit Mac a list with 1 million strings takes nearly 44 MB of memory; the 7MB reported is not nearly enough even for a 32-bit system. I calculated that size using the `sys.getsizeof()` function to measure the memory requirements of a single `'1'` string multiplied by 1 million, plus the size of a list object with 1 million references.

Comment: Hrm, unless the `'1'` string is interned (which it is in my tests); then the list indeed only takes 7.6 MB, so that would be consistent. The other candidate here is the `recipe.total_size()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your patient.In my real program,i found one thing that i can't understand.It is the memory taken by container is much smaller than by "for".So i make this demo test.The memory caused by "for" is not equal to by container.One is 7.645 MB, another is 62.656 MB.The way that you calculated the size of list by using the sys.getsizeof(), i did it too.My purpose is to reduce the memory.So 62.656 MB is more important to me than 7.645.:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely desperate to reduce memory usage on the loop you can do it this way:

```
i = 0
while 1:
    try:
        a[i]  #accessing an element here
        i += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Memory stats (if they are accurate):

```
12     9.215 MB     0.000 MB       i = 0
13     9.215 MB     0.000 MB       while 1:
14    60.484 MB    51.270 MB           try:
15    60.484 MB     0.000 MB               a[i]
16    60.484 MB     0.000 MB               i += 1
17    60.484 MB     0.000 MB           except IndexError:
18    60.484 MB     0.000 MB               break
```

However, this code looks ugly and danger and reduction in memory usage is just tiny.

Comment: Why would you do that range than `for i in range(...)`?

Comment: xrange yields values instead of storing them in memory. So in case of large sequences, can help save memory. However, sadly in this particular case it seems like it did not helped, possibly because it yields just integers. And this is why I changed my solution to better, but only from perspective of memory usage.

Comment: @jentyk: You did well.You really reduce some memory usage.But i can't use it in my project, you know why.:-)I expect a better idea.

Comment: P.S. I can't use the xrange.Because the list "a" is the query result in my project.

Comment: The problem is not very well defined, I am afraid. I am not sure are you expecting overall memory usage reduction or in this specific place in your code? If a is a query, maybe using ORM with Lazy Loading would help you? To answer the question and not just keep guessing we would need well defined question.

Comment: You are right, it's my fault.I will try it better next time.Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of `list iterator`. You should use `generator`. according to your sample code:

```
@profile
def test():
    a = ("1" for i in range(10**6))   #this will return a generator, instead of a list.
    for i in a:
        pass
```

Now if you use the `generator 'a'` in the `for loop`, it won't take that much memory.

2) If you are getting a `list`, then first convert it into `generator`.

```
@profile
def test():
    a = ["1"] * (10**6)  #getting list
    g = (i for i in a)   #converting list into a generator object
    for i in g:          #use generator object for iteration
        pass
```

Try this. If is helps you.

Comment: Thanks,but in my real program, the query result is instead of list "a".Twisted dbapi returns it.It can't be converted to generator.It makes me mad.

Comment: 1)It did work in this demo test.But in my game program, "a" is the query result from db.It is a list.

Comment: 2)It takes the 63.867 MB memory.